# host java web application on remote server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications, hosting

I developed an web application using spring and hibernate.i bought domain name and hosting but now i can not understand how to host this application.i don't know how to install Apache tomcat on this remote server and how to install JDK.

I tried to install tomcat using putty but it showing an error "Network Error :Connection refused"

Can someone provide me details how to host an java application in remote Linux server. I am using windows 7 by the way.

i created war.now i need to deploy this war in tomcat.but how do i install tomcat on that remote server.I want to know A-Z how to host java web app on remote server.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have said you already bought a hosting solution, but I have had good experiences with DigitalOcean. They provide lots of documentation on getting started to host web applications and servers. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) is a link to them describing how to install Apache Tomcat on a remote linux server, perhaps this will be helpful.